# MySQL - query help select results with latest timestamp grouped by date

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table containing the following fields:
date, time, node, result
describing some numeric result for different nodes at different dates and times throughout each day. Typical listing will look something like this:

```
date       | time  | node | result
----------------------------------
2011-03-01 | 10:02 | A    | 10
2011-03-01 | 11:02 | A    | 20
2011-03-02 | 03:13 | A    | 23
2011-03-02 | 12:15 | A    | 18
2011-03-02 | 13:15 | A    | 8
2011-03-01 | 13:12 | B    | 2
2011-03-01 | 14:26 | B    | 1
2011-03-02 | 08:00 | B    | 6
2011-03-02 | 07:22 | B    | 3
2011-03-02 | 21:19 | B    | 4
```

I want to form a query that'll get the last result from each day for each node, such that I'd get something like this:

```
date       | time  | node | latest
-----------------------------------
2011-03-01 | 11:02 | A    | 20
2011-03-01 | 14:26 | B    | 1
2011-03-02 | 13:15 | A    | 8
2011-03-02 | 21:19 | B    | 4
```

I thought about doing a `group by date, node`, but then extracting the last value was a mess (I used `group_concat( result order by time )` and used `SUBSTRING()` to get the last value. Baah, I know). Is there a simple way to do this in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I saw a similar request solving it very nice without using an `INNER JOIN` but I can't find it right now (and it might have been SQL Server) but following should work nevertheless.

```
SELECT n.*
FROM   Nodes n
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(time) AS Time
                , Date
                , Node
         FROM   Nodes
         GROUP BY
                Date
                , Node
       ) nm ON nm.time = n.time
               AND nm.Date = n.Date
               AND nm.Node = n.Node
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you would have to use something like the Max() function.  Sorry I don't have mysql, so I can't test but I would think something like this

```
select t.date, t.node, t.latest, Max(time) from Table t Group By t.node, t.date
```

I think the aggregate function will return only the one row per grouping.